# webkit: Hardware accelerated layer makes all text on the page fuzzy

Tags: css, webkit, repaint, hardware-acceleration

I have a fixed `background-image` page. I'm trying to prevent onscroll repaints by putting the background-image in its own layer.

So i created an element inside body with `position:fixed` and `backface-visibility: hidden` to prevent repaints. That works well, but the text in my page now renders a little fuzzy. Text renders sharp again if i toggle the `backface-visibility` but then the layer repaints on scroll

This is bizzare to me because i also have a fixed header on my page using the same `position` and `backface-visibility` and it does not cause any problems

Why does the background-image layer cause fuzzy font rendering on a different layer? How can i prevent it?

P.S. This only happens on chrome & opera which makes me believe this exclusive to webkit.

with `backface-visibility`: http://postimg.org/image/l4owgl00d/

without: http://postimg.org/image/c8e4cn9e5/

Comment: Are you doing any 3D transform that you're not telling about? If not, `backface-visibility` shouldn't make any difference at all

Comment: @cs-smile added screenshots to question. 

@Amit no. But i believe `backface-visibility` has the same effect as a 3d transform, it kicks in hardware acceleration

Answer (score 0):

"with backface-visibility" screenshot is rendered with gray-scale antialiasing.

Another one is rendered with cleartype (sub-pixel) antialiasing.

That's why you see the difference.

Gray-scale antialiasing is used when text gets rendered on bitmap buffers having transparent background.

To fix that I'd suggest to define `background-color:#fff;` on that element so to give it solid background.

Comment: Just tried that, doesn't seem to be helping. I also tried `-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` with no luck

Comment: Check if you have any 3D transformations applied by default. Usually they affect such rendering behavior as content gets rendered into texture (bitmap). For 3D transformation purposes gray-scale antialiasing is the only reasonable option.

Comment: I checked, no transforms are being applied. I even added `* {transform: none !important;}`. The issue persists

Comment: then it could be a detail of webkit interpretation of `backface-visibility`. It triggers creation of bitmap buffer for some reason.